# On which side of the body should we lay while sleeping and why?

Tags: ayurveda

On which side of the body should we lay while sleeping and why? Is there any preferable side according to Hinduism?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86909/discussion-on-question-by-macindows-on-which-side-of-the-body-should-we-lay-whil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Garuḍa Mahā-Purāṇa, we must sleep on our left side.

> [Chapter 46](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122521.html), Agastya Saṃhitā
>
> वामपार्श्वेन स्वपिति नात्र कार्य्या विचारणा  ॥ [४६.३०.अ](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AA%E0%A5%AC) ॥
>
> > 30. (a). **One must sleep on their left side; there's nothing to be questioned in this regard.**
>
> English Translation by M.N. Dutt

An Ayurvedic compendium on ancient Indian Chemical Medicine (*Rasa-śāstra*) named - "Rasa-jala-Nidhi" also recommends sleeping on left side, along with giving the reason for doing so.

> [Part 16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rasa-jala-nidhi-volume-4/d/doc220439.html) - Directions for sleeping
>
> ... then to recline on the left side with a view to sleep...
>
> The digesting heat in the stomach is situated on the left side of the
> belly, a little higher up the navel. It is, therefore, always
> desirable to lie down on the left side after taking the meal. One
> should also rub the palm of the feet with oil at the time one retires
> to bed for sleep;

Comment: I remember my mom used to say the same thing. Sleep on your left. Roll to your right while waking up.

Comment: And happy I got an answer after 3 years 

Comment: Glad, I could be of help, even if after 3 years! :)) @Macindows

Comment: Was taught to sleep on my back, always  Though it’s very difficult and we shift positions without knowing while asleep.